# Options to compile and build jar files dynamically/programmatically?

Tags: java, compilation, eclipse-jdt

The scenario is that I have a bunch of java projects with source files and lib jar files (for example apache-commons). I have multiple projects like that in different locations (shared drives, web servers, etc). Some of these projects depend on others. For example the output (.jar) from one project is used to compile and produce output for an other.

What I want to do is, programmatically (headless), using java, collect the source files and libs for all projects, compile them in order, and at the end produce jar files for the end projects. So, for project #1, brings all source files to a directory, bring all dependent libs in the same directory, compile, and create a .jar. Then do the same for project #2 but also include in the libs (or class path) the output of project #1, etc.

The projects dependency is known. The order on which the projects need to compile is known.

Bringing the source files and lib files together is not a problem. What I am looking for is suggestions on how to go about compiling programmatically. One option that I am considering is maybe Eclipse JDT. But before I go that path, I would like to see what other similar options exist out there

(I do understand that there are better procedures and processes that can be followed in order to make it easier to get the end result but I have no control over those. The build needs to be done dynamically/programmatically as described above)

Comment: You're apparently looking for a build tool, like Gradle or Maven.

Comment: ... and possibly a build server, like Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, I would think that launching a process to invoke a Maven command would be the best way to "build a bunch of projects with inter-dependencies".  Re-inventing that wheel seems like too much work.